# Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. For any applicaitonUrl

Tags: c#

After not working on my project for a week I tried to launch the project and I get the following URI.

`Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.`

I found that changing the `launchSettings.json` can make it work.

I changed `"applicationUrl": "http://*:900"` to `"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:900"` and that fixed the issue. However, I am uncertain if it would cause issues on clients sites.

What I would like to know is why I am getting the issue in the first place and why the `any IP` wildcard does not work.

Comment: `*:9000` looks like a *binding*, and it is indeed *not* a URL. In any case, the launch settings are development artifacts and should not be used “on client sites”.

Comment: @user2864740 what would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: There is no such thing as an “any IP” URL.. so the core issue is a bad URL. What is putting it in, and why? Perhaps it is being confused with [an IIS wildcard binging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support)?

Comment: It is also unclear from the question how “client sites” apply, as they should not be using launchSettings at all! See https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/launchsettings-json-debug-profile-in-asp-net-core/ — these settings apply *only to development*, and should be configured per the given development environment(s).